# All files from webpacker on production is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, webpacker

I tried to deploy RoR 5.2 app on Heroku and DigitalOcean, and got the same problem. All files from webpacker is undefined, when you click on them from browser inspector.

What can be wrong? Screenshot attached.

[undefined webpacker files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGY1F.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. To be able to answer your question you have to provide some more information. If you could add your `Gemfile`, `webpacker.yml` and your production config would be a good start.

Comment: Without knowing the real issue, you can try to set up your application with a Vue on Rails application template ~>
`rails new app -m http://vueonrails.com/vue`